# How can I use raw_input together with a function and get output in Git Bash?

Tags: function, git-bash, raw-input

After having used a raw_input, I want to use a function to give an answer according to the input of the user.

```
level = raw_input("Choose: A, B, C.")
def determination_level(level):
    if determination_level == "A":
        print "You have chosen the level 'A'."
    elif determination_level == "B":
        print "You have chosen the level 'B'."
    elif determination_level == "C":
        print "You have chosen the level 'C'."
    else:
        print "Wrong input!"
```

Using Git Bash, there is unfortunately no output. How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Could it be that I have to call the function while writing determination_level(level) at the end of the code?

Comment: just forgot to call the function. Now it works!